# How to make an android app for a sketching robot like Line-us?

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I am working on android app for a sketching robot(a robot that does painting) like [this](https://www.line-us.com/.) 
.This robot skecthes exactly the same on a board as the user sketches on a mobile screen as you can see the in the above video link.
I have already setup my hardware which is comprised of four stepper motors,arduino with bluetooth module.I have connected those motors with my app via bluetooth and I control these motors via this bluetooth connection.I have also implemented the drawing functionality on my android app When the user sketches something on mobile screen the x,y distance sketched and direction of the sketch drawn should be sent to robot.The android code is [here](https://github.com/AsifAlee/MotionApp).
The following is createActivity screenshot with a rough sketch drawn.
[image]

1. Now the problem is when when I touch the screen  alot of pixels
   positions are generated which are different on various dpi screens.I
   am confused how can I scale these values
2. The second issued is android screen coordinate system is like inverted first quadrant.A we go down the value of y increases.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how can I scale my x,y values so that for certain distance  in x or y direction the respective robot arm move a specific distance in the same direction as x or y.

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities. I looked into the code. Your PaintView class is saving each point that user draws into a list called "pointsLists". The paintview calass is your drawing area in layout (activity_create.xml) and has a fixed size of 50 mm * 25 mm.

This pointslists can be called by `paintView.paintViewPoints()` by other activities such as `creatAcivity.java`.

It seems the painting is done inside a bitmap. You can change the bitmap size by calling `paintView.onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh);`

The simplest way to solve your question should be adding this line into CreateActivity.java class (after setcontentview line):

`paintView.onSizeChanged(5,10,25,50); //reducing the scale to 1:5 in this case`

Comment: I have not setup the arm yet but the arm just consists of  two motors x and y.I can send values to the motors and they are responding to my values

Comment: can you show the code how you send the values to the motor? then we can figure out how to scale them. pls update your question with more details and codes. After you added the codes, mention me here to notify.

Comment: I have updated the question  and added the link to github

Comment: What if I add the paintView dimensions as 300dp width and 150dp height

Comment: u can't as the width and height of the view is fixed in your layout and they should be doubled. If you want to change this ratio, first change the view width and height from layout. if the answer work, pls accept it.

Comment: sorry I had mistakenly set the PaintView width to 300px and height  to 150px actually they are 300dp by 150dp.Will you please update your answer for these values ?

Comment: go to your layout (activity_create.xmp) and change the width and height of your paintview from 50 mm and 25 mm to something else like 300 dp and 150 dp. This is your original size. then you should be able to use `paintView.onSizeChanged(100,50,300,150);`